# Something like ICE inside of tank of gas water heater, what should I do?

Tags: water-heater

I saw the ice stuff inside of my tank when I try to change my Pressure relief valve, is this real ice or something else? this thing really scares me when I saw it, just like the alien's baby nest, lol. I took the photo through the PRV hole.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Harper just attached the pics, do you have some idea what's that? I took the pic through the pressure relife valve hole

Comment: why don't you scoop some out and examine it?

Comment: Is it glass?  Most gas tanks are glass lined, perhaps it’s a manufacturing artifact.

Comment: Is that inside the tank where the water is or is outside the water tank and inside the outer cover?

Comment: The cold water supply is obviously turned off so drain the tank with the drain valve and report what comes out. Sample this stuff you see with some sort of spatula and determine what it is.

Comment: Parts of a corroded annode could be 1 possibility most folks don't realize these need to be changed to extend the water heaters service life.